# Countertop receptacle spacing issue

Tags: electrical

I am rewiring my kitchen and I have installed 28 inch wide windows. NEC states that there should be no space along the countertop that is more than 24 inches from the nearest outlet. With the window trim installed, I don't believe that there will be enough space between the countertop and the window (unless I put the box in sideways, but then this would complicate the back-splash) to install a receptacle. Would it be permissible to have the spacing in this particular location to be more than 24 inches (approximately 30-32 inches), or must I do something about this?

Answer (score 5):

The rule says that there must be an outlet within 24 inches horizontally from any location along the countertop, so the outlets can be up to 48 inches apart!  Think of it as if you have a blender with a 2 ft long cord.  Ignoring the height of the outlet, you should be able to plug the blender in anywhere you place it along the counter wall.

Comment: This is right.  It is that simple.  You cannot be more than 24 inches from an outlet (given you are standing next to wall).  Meaning if you have outlets 48 inches away then you are 24 inches from two.  In your specific case I would install them about 6 inches off the windows on each side.

Answer (score 1):

This is where reading the actual wording of the code is useful.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection
>
> #### Article 210 Branch Circuits
>
> #### *III Required Outlets*
>
> **210.52 Dwelling Unit Receptacle Outlets**
>
> **(C) Coutertops**
>
> **(1) Wall Countertop Spaces.** A receptacle outlet shall be installed at each wall countertop space that is 300 mm (12 in.) or wider. Receptacle outlets shall be installed so that no point along the wall line is more than 600 mm (24 in.) measured horizontally from a receptacle outlet in that space.

If you pick any point along the wall, there should be at least one receptacle within 24" (600 mm) of that point.  So receptacles can be placed 48" apart (center to center).